# Python: Print all numbers in range divisible by x and y

Tags: python

I'm trying to print all numbers in range 1-100 that are divisible by x and y (ie. 2 nad 3). For now i have

```
for x in range(0, 101):
    if x % (2 and 3) == 0: print("2, 3: ", x)
    elif x % 2 == 0: print("2: ", x)
    elif x % 3 == 0: print("3: ", x)
```

But it is not accurate, any suggestions?

Comment: in second line use x%6 instead of x%(2 and 3)

Comment: If you want from 1 to 100, then change your range to (1,102)

Comment: @StefanPochmann Just got to know this from the accepted answer see my comment there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(2 and 3)` evaluates to `3`, that's why you never see the condition `elif x % 3 == 0` being executed, notice there's no `print("3: ", x)` in the output of your code, because it'd already fallen into the condition `if x % (2 and 3) == 0`.

You should be better using `if ((x % 2) == 0 and (x % 3) == 0) : print("2, 3: ", x)` on that line.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Perfect indeed, my bad, I'll edit the answer accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Python amused me with `2 and 3` returning `3`. This info is can't be digested easily. Though i just check after I saw your answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is not accurate is by writing `x % (2 and 3)` python is interpreting (2 and 3).(https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html)

in python (2 and 3) would return 3 because both values are "truthy" and the AND comparison operator in python will return the last value when both items are `True`.

As per Rajesh Kumar's suggestion you could do 

`if x % 6 == 0: # ...`

or

`if x % 2 == 0 and x % 3 == 0: # More verbose...`

Answer (score -1):

If you have a number that hast to be dividable by number `x` and number `y` you can look at it like:
If some rest is left after a division with divisor `x` or divisor `y`, the currently considered number `toDivide` is not the number you are looking for, because you want numbers where neither of the devisions results in a rest.

```
x = 2
y = 3
for toDivide in range(1, 101):
    # can't divide by x and y
    if toDivide%x and toDivide%y:
        continue
    print((str(x)+", "+str(y) if not toDivide%x and not toDivide%y else (str(x) if not toDivide%x else str(y)))+":"+str(toDivide))
```

edit: found and resolved the code-error

Answer (score -2):

In `if x % (2 and 3) == 0` the value of (2 and 3) is evaluated first, you should first check divisibility by 2 then by 3. i.e.

```
if (x % 2) and (x % 3)
```

the two expressions in brackets return booleans that you finally evaluate using `and`.

corrected:

```
for x in range(0, 101):
    if (x % 2) and (x % 3): 
        print("2, 3: ", x)
    elif x % 2 == 0: 
        print("2: ", x)
    elif x % 3 == 0: 
        print("3: ", x)
```

Comment: `(2 and 3)` being evaluated first has nothing to do with operator precedence.

Comment: I wanted to mean the values in bracket are evaluated first.